# mysql if - como aplicar em registros iguais

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

Olá! pessoal estou tentando fazer um select e aplicar uma regra somente nos registros iguais. Preciso que todos os registros sejam listados, porém naqueles q são iguais, uma regra específica seja aplicada;

Por exemplo, selecionar todos os registros de clientes, e em todos que possuírem o mesmo codDeReferencia, agrupar e mostrar somente o q possui o campo dataAlteracao diferente de vazio;

Estou tentando assim:

```
select * from clientes group by codDeReferencia where id in(select distinct codDeReferencia from clientes where dataAlteracao!='')
```

Comment: Sugiro você colocar uns dados de prova pra que a gente possa-lhe ajudar.
Pelo que vc sugere poder ter um "group by + having" mas sem os dados é difícil.. Cria um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) e compartilha